# How accurate can TeX be? Question about fonts

Tags: fonts

This is a constructed example. As you can see as an example, there are three characters in a line (A). The third character is shifted to the left, until it covers the second one. If the \hskip is optimal, the second letter is perfectly covered and does not accur to be bold, shaded or doubled. But it does not work with any character.
Why is this possible, using the same font? Is this an inaccuracy of TeX or does it depend on other variables? (Computer, display,letter-spacing..others?)

```
\newdimen\test
\test=1Em

\def\myspace#1#2{#1\hbox{#1\hskip#2\test\ #1}\vskip\baselineskip}
%
\magnification=2200%
Example : \myspace{A}{-0}%
\myspace{A}{-1.084}%
\myspace{B}{-1.084}%
\myspace{C}{-1.084}%
\myspace{D}{-1.084}%
\myspace{E}{-1.084}%
%
\bye
```

Comment: You are shifting the letters by a fixed amount (-1.084em), but not all letters have that width.  Try with a `W` and your horizontal shift is not nearly enough.  Try with `I` and it's so big it covers the first letter instead.

Comment: @ Phelype Oleinik  With \tt it's obvious, but why have the letters within the same font a different spacing? A matter of (I do not have the right word) asthetics?

Comment: almost all fonts have i less wide tham m just monospace (typewriter) fonts as selected by  `\tt` have equal spacing. Also why are you forcing a word space (`\ ` ) after the negative space between the letters?

Comment: @MatthiasBorck-Elsner They don't have a different spacing (the space is always the same in your tests), they have different character _widths_.

Comment: @ Phelype Oleinik Right, I meant the widths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were spacing by a fixed amount ignoring the width of the letter.

plain tex (and latex) has an `\llap` macro that overprints its content to the left taking no horizontal space

[image]

```
\newdimen\test
\test=1Em

\def\myspace#1#2{#1\hbox{#1\llap{#1}}\vskip\baselineskip}
%
\magnification=2200%
Example : \myspace{A}{-0}%
\myspace{A}{-1.084}%
\myspace{B}{-1.084}%
\myspace{C}{-1.084}%
\myspace{D}{-1.084}%
\myspace{E}{-1.084}%
%
\bye
```

this ignores the second argument and overprints the 1st argument

---

Note you asked about tex, tex uses exact integer arithmetic so accuracy isn't really an issue at all. However (especially if you use longer text runs rather than a single letter) the final position of the second text is backspaced by the amount specified by TeX (the sum of the advance widths of the glyphs used using TeX arithmetic) from the current point (the sum of the advance widths as calculated by the pdf renderer) any difference would be well below the humanly visible range but could potentially affect the snapping to pixel boundaries of the physical device, also even if the text is positioned at exactly identical pdf position the double printing may or may not affect the anti-aliasing heuristics of the pdf renderer so may still at low resolutions be visible.

Comment: What does "overprinting" by \llap mean? Is the character really overprinted (printed again) or is it just replaced?

Comment: @MatthiasBorck-Elsner Yes, `\llap` implies a secondary typeset overtop of previous material, in this case

Comment: @MatthiasBorck-Elsner no the `#1` prints it and then `\llap{#1}` prints it again overprinting whatever is to the left, which is the same character in this case

Comment: @David Carlisle Sorry to be insisting: Is the original character deleted and printed new, or is the original character left in place, overprinted by the new (or same) character?

Comment: no once you have typeset a character in tex you can't actually remove it, the character is printed twice in the PDf, in the same position. change `#1\llap{#1}` to `?\llap{#1}` and you will see the character overprinting ?

Comment: @David Carlisle About your last improvement:Thougt so.  Does it say, if I want to be really (really..) accurate, I have to adjust TeX to the capabilties of the display? (Screen, printer?)   Most readers would not recognize, it is just a theoretical question.  But sometimes, I see the difference.

Comment: @MatthiasBorck-Elsner no I  think if you overprint it may always be visible in some pdf viewers due to the antialiasing (but I'm not 100% certain about that)